# ExtJS 6 Check if event was fired programmatically

Tags: extjs, extjs6

How I can check if event was fired programmatically?

Namely I have an [`Ext.tree.Panel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.tree.Panel.html) and listen for it `selectionchange` event. How I can check within handler if event was fired manually by user (row click) or via `select()` method?

Answer (score 1):

option 1 :
For most of the events eOpts arguments is passed to event. Depending on the event this is fill by ExtJs. If event is fired manually thus eOpts is never filled or filled customly.

option 2:
If manual event firing is happens in code you can manipulate add a custom argument

---

As far as I know and my research there is no solution based on scope of selectionchange event. However from a design perspective this is how it should be since selectionchange event should not depend on caller. From what is told I can say that 2 different event is needed. Where different action is taken. (which is the definition of an event :))

Therefore my suggestion is to override select method and fire a custom event in which you do what you want do differently. If needed in rowclick event another custom event can be fired.

You can override this in subclasses or you can use Ext.override for global scope.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but...
Option 1: `eOpts` is actually options object passed to `Ext.util.Observable.addListener`, so it is always filled. Some events pass `e` argument to the handler.
Option 2: Its work only if event was programmatically fired using `fireEvent` method.

Comment: Actually I have workaround for this issue, but I'm trying to find better solution.

Comment: ok I misunderstand the problem I thought you were trying differ programatically fireEvent call vs event appearing.

Comment: Nah, its really bad idea. I can just add additional property to my component to determine if last event was fired programmatically or not. Its bad solution too imo, but not that bad. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. The "best" way would be to listen for an `itemclick` event and check whether the `selectionchange` event fired within some small threshold amount.

Comment: If think this way I can listen to `itemclick` and `selectionchange` event separately. Within `itemclick` I can implement basic selection logic and call `select()` silently.

Comment: A click doesn't necessarily mean a selection though. Selection can happen through other means. I guess it depends on your use case. The `select` event occurs via a selection. What triggers the selection isn't a concern at that point for the framework.